# jruby concurrent pool threads mixing up when combined for result

Tags: threadpool, jruby

There is an array with indices [[0, n_0], [1, n_1], ..., [n, n_n]]. For each n_i a function is called. It is necessary to reorder the result from the threads by first component after every thread has terminated. As far as I could find a way to do this, I organized that the index is hard-coded by asking if the index is e.g. 0 and then starting the code separately for the hard-coded index 0. So far this a possible way to do it (even though the code looks as if someone didn't understand what a loop is for).

```
rest = []
tpl.each do |idx, vn|
    if idx == 0
        pool.post do
            res = funk(vn)
p ['idx 0: ', res]
            rest += [[0, res]]
        end#pool.post
    elsif idx == 1
        pool.post do
            res = funk(vn)
p ['idx 1: ', res]
            rest += [[1, res]]
        end#pool.post
end;end
```

But now there is a strange behaviour:
Index 0 and 1 are calculated accurately, but when the result of 1 is added one line later, the result of the former function is added (again).

```
["idx 1: ", [4]]
["idx 0: ", [16900]]
rest: [[0, [16900]], [1, [16900], ...]
```

This is not always the case, so it depends on the order of the appearance of the results.
If e.g. the calculation of index 0 is finished after the calculation of index 1, then idx 1 is missing, or wrong. But other cases  of confused results also appear: idx 0 before idx 1, but result of idx 0 is the result of idx 1.

?

It looks like if the threads are not really separated. Can that be enforced, or is there a smarter way of keeping indeces?

Answer (score 0):

One option, I found out, is to synchronize the threads, but that would make the algorithm slower again, so a better solution is:

The results don't get mixed up, if the rest-tuple already has the structure to differentiate the results coming in:

```
rest = [[], []]
tpl.each do |idx, vn|
    if idx == 0
        pool.post do
            res = funk(vn)
p ['idx 0: ', res]
            rest[0] << [0, res]
        end#pool.post
    elsif idx == 1
        pool.post do
            res = funk(vn)
p ['idx 1: ', res]
            rest[1] << [1, res]
        end#pool.post
end;end
```